How do I create an object where the values are results of running the key through a function?
I want to create an object where the keys are defined in a literal type and the values are then the result of running each key through a function. The idea is to have an object that is defined by the entries in the literal type. I also want to be able to add different values for specific keys, these keys shouldn't be run through the function that the rest are run through.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:
function capitalizeString(string: string) {
  return string[0].toUpperCase() + string.substring(1)
}

type fruits = "apple" | "orange" | "pineapple" | "pear" | "orange" | "melon"

const fruitObject:{ [key in fruits]: string} = {
  // Would create key/value pairs of all of the entries in the literal type
  [key]: capitalizeString(key),
  // custom values that aren't being handled by the function
  orange: "oRaNgE",
  melon: "meloN",
}

This is a simple example and I know that there are better ways to fix this specific issue, but I'm more interested in whether or not this can be done than how this specific example could be improved.

"an object where the keys are defined in a literal type" - that is not possible. The literal type does not exist at runtime. If you want to write such a function, you will have to pass the keys as values explicitly.

In you're fruitObject definition, you are trying to perform some sort of comprehension which is not really possible is TypeScript. However, there is still a solution to your problem.
First, we cannot loop over union types as they exist in a type domain. Instead, we can create a readonly list containing the keys and extract its type. This then effectively allows us to loop over the union type.
const fruits = ["apple", "orange", "pineapple", "pear", "orange", "melon"] as const;
type Fruits = (typeof fruits)[number];
type FruitObject = {[Key in Fruits]: string}

Fruits will now be a union type of "apple", "orange", "pineapple" etc. the same as your original fruits type. With this method, we can edit the array to contain more fruit and everything will update accordingly.
Next, we need to create a function that accept a list of fruits and reduces that array into an object:
function fruitObjectFactory(fruitArray: readonly Fruits[]): FruitObject {
  return fruitArray.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = capitalizeString(key);
    return acc;
  }, {} as FruitObject);
}

This can be done using an arrays .reduce() method where the accumulator is of type FruitObject.
Finally, we can then call this function in our object definition and using the spread operator (...), we can combine the two objects.
const fruitObject: FruitObject = {
  ...fruitObjectFactory(fruits),
  orange: "oRaNgE",
  melon: "meloN",
}

You'll notice that ...fruitObjectFactory(fruits) will create an object captilising all strings in the fruits array but you wanted exceptions. The definition of orange: "oRaNgE" and melon: "meloN" overwrite the orange: "Orange" and melon: "Melon" key-value pair respectively.
Note that the readonly in the .reduce() callback method is not required. I only added it so I could pass in the original fruits array which is of type readonly due to the as const operator.
